# What am I doing wrong with my Python code?

Tags: python

I am working on my final project for my Intro to Principles of Computer Programming class, I took an old project to find item prices from a list and converted it to show an NFL team's final score.

My first code that works:

```
#Start Program

foundItemFlag = False
itemNum = (34, 124, 178, 219, 225) 
price = (3.76, 1.29, 4.78, 2.76, 4.51) 
input = int(input("Enter the Item Number: "))
for k in range (5):
    if input == itemNum[k]:
        foundItemFlag = True
        print("The item number you've chosen is ", input, "and the price is ", price[k])
if (foundItemFlag == False):
    print("Invalid Item Number!")

#End Program
```

Here is my converted code that I am trying to fix..

```
#Start Program

foundTeamFlag = False
teamName = ("Bills", "Dolphins", "Patriots", "Jets", "Ravens", "Bengals", "Browns", "Steelers", "Texans", "Colts", "Jaguars", "Titans", "Broncos", "Chiefs", "Raiders", "Chargers") 
final = (6-10, 7-9, "12-4", "6-10", "10-6", "10-6", "5-11", "8-8", "12-4", "11-5", "2-14", "6-10", "13-3", "2-14", "4-12", "7-9") 
input = int(input("To find your team's final record for last season please type in their name (Ravens, Texans and etc) :"))
for k in range (5):
    if input == teamName[k]:
        foundTeamFlag = True
        print("The ", input, "final record for 2012-2013 was ", final[k])
if (foundTeamFlag == False):
    print("Oops, check your team name and try again!")

#End Program
```

I am very much a beginner and copied my code into IDLE and received this error for the NFL code:

```
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

Comment: To start, avoid using a variable name that is the same as a method name.  In this case, `input` is being used as both a method and as a data variable.

Comment: I don't get a `SyntaxError`.  there is however an error where you ask for the team's name and then try to convert it to an integer.

Comment: You should also learn about dictionaries.  Instead of two tuples, you could make one dict: `finals = {'Bills':'6-10', 'Dolphins':'7-9'}` Then, `print finals['Bills']` will print '6-10' without the need to search (with your loop) or convert a name to an integer.

Comment: You've got a variety of problems, none of which I can identify as a syntax error. Issues: `final` includes a couple of integers instead of strings; you only loop over the first five elements of `teamName` (use `for k in xrange(len(teamName))`; you name a variable `input`, which overrides a built-in function, and you try to convert a string to an `int` when parsing your input. Also I assume you're using Python 3, but if you're in Python 2, you should be using `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Have you tried running this code from the command line?  It might be an issue related to copy-paste + IDLE.

Comment: This would probably be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using Python 3.X? Here's a list of things you're doing wrong:

1. Converting user's input (string) to an int: this is not going to work
2. Reassigning built-in "input" to variable name
3. Only iterating over the first 5 elements of the the variable "final"
4. As pointed out by the other answerer, you probably want to use strings in your "final" tuple

I would do something as follows (For python 3.x, replace `raw_input` with `input`):

```
foundTeamFlag = False
teamName = ("Bills", "Dolphins", "Patriots", "Jets", "Ravens", "Bengals", "Browns", "Steelers", "Texans", "Colts", "Jaguars", "Titans", "Broncos", "Chiefs", "Raiders", "Chargers") 
finalScores = ("6-10", "7-9", "12-4", "6-10", "10-6", "10-6", "5-11", "8-8", "12-4", "11-5", "2-14", "6-10", "13-3", "2-14", "4-12", "7-9") 
userInput = raw_input("To find your team's final record for last season please type in their name (Ravens, Texans and etc) :")
for name, score in zip(teamName, finalScores):
    if userInput == name:
        foundTeamFlag = True
        print("The ", userInput, "final record for 2012-2013 was ", score)
        break
if (foundTeamFlag == False):
    print("Oops, check your team name and try again!")
```

Comment: `final` isn't a builtin in Python.

Comment: @HenryKeiter you're right, my bad. Edited

Comment: Alright so its best not to use the input as a variable by itself? Always add to it? I am googling tuples now, havent heard that term yet!

Comment: Also what is the purpose of zip?

Comment: @JoshuaHook when you use input as a variable name, you over-ride the built-in Python command also called "input". Generally, this is a bad idea because this can lead to unexpected behavior in your code. For your reference, [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) is the list of Python built-in functions.

Comment: @JoshuaHook zip is another of those built-ins we keep talking about. Basically, it takes as input several iterables (lists/tuples...), and returns them pair-wise. For example, zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']) will return (1, 'a'), (2, 'b') etc... quite handy for iterating over 2 related lists as in your case

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `final` is one problem :

```
final = (6-10, 7-9, "12-4", "6-10", "10-6", "10-6", "5-11", "8-8", "12-4", "11-5", "2-14", "6-10", "13-3", "2-14", "4-12", "7-9")
```

There are subtraction statements there (first 2). Change them to strings:

```
final = ("6-10", "7-9", "12-4", "6-10", "10-6", "10-6", "5-11", "8-8", "12-4", "11-5", "2-14", "6-10", "13-3", "2-14", "4-12", "7-9")
```

Also, never use names like `input`,`list`,`pass` as variable names...

As pointed out by the commenters that is not the main one,

- You are asking the user to input name of the team, but are converting that to an integer..
- You are iterating over the first 5 elements of the tuple only...

Your final code should be:

```
foundTeamFlag = False
teamName = ("Bills", "Dolphins", "Patriots", "Jets", "Ravens", "Bengals", "Browns", "Steelers", "Texans", "Colts", "Jaguars", "Titans", "Broncos", "Chiefs", "Raiders", "Chargers") 
teams = ("6-10", "7-9", "12-4", "6-10", "10-6", "10-6", "5-11", "8-8", "12-4", "11-5", "2-14", "6-10", "13-3", "2-14", "4-12", "7-9") 
inp = input("To find your team's final record for last season please type in their name (Ravens, Texans and etc) : ")
for k in range(len(teams)):
    if inp == teamName[k]:
        foundTeamFlag = True
        print("The ", input, "final record for 2012-2013 was ", teams[k])
if (foundTeamFlag == False):
    print("Oops, check your team name and try again!")
```

But a more flexible approach would be to use a dictionary:

```
dic = {'Bengals': '10-6', 'Bills': '6-10', 'Broncos': '13-3','Browns': '5-11',
 'Chargers': '7-9', 'Chiefs': '2-14', 'Colts': '11-5', 'Dolphins': '7-9',
 'Jaguars': '2-14', 'Jets': '6-10', 'Patriots': '12-4', 'Raiders': '4-12',
 'Ravens': '10-6', 'Steelers': '8-8', 'Texans': '12-4', 'Titans': '6-10'}
name = input('Enter the name of the team you want the records of: ')
data = dic.get(name)
if data != None:
    print("The ", name, "final record for 2012-2013 was ", data)
```

Comment: What is wrong with it exactly?

Comment: Wait, what is wrong with that tuple?  I mean, I realize he probably doesn't intend to have ints mixed with strings, but shouldn't that tuple NOT break code?

Comment: You're right about that being an error in the code.  However, it doesn't cause the SyntaxError.

Comment: Yes, this is logically wrong, but it doesn't cause the problem he described.

Comment: @HenryKeiter You are right too. Thanks...

Comment: @BlackVegetable Yes.. Good point, corrected..

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing data types. For example, in the `final` tuple there are numbers, and strings. Also, where you read the input you're asking for a team name, which is a string, but converting it as if it were an `int`. For starters, try this:

```
foundTeamFlag = False
teamName = ("Bills", "Dolphins", "Patriots", "Jets", "Ravens", "Bengals", "Browns", "Steelers", "Texans", "Colts", "Jaguars", "Titans", "Broncos", "Chiefs", "Raiders", "Chargers")
final = ("6-10", "7-9", "12-4", "6-10", "10-6", "10-6", "5-11", "8-8", "12-4", "11-5", "2-14", "6-10", "13-3", "2-14", "4-12", "7-9")
inp = raw_input("To find your team's final record for last season please type in their name (Ravens, Texans and etc) : ")

for k in range(5):
    if inp == teamName[k]:
        foundTeamFlag = True
        print("The ", inp, "final record for 2012-2013 was ", final[k])
        break

if foundTeamFlag == False:
    print("Oops, check your team name and try again!")
```

Now, for a more Pythonic way to solve this problem, ditch the loop and use a dictionary like this:

```
teamName = ("Bills", "Dolphins", "Patriots", "Jets", "Ravens", "Bengals", "Browns", "Steelers", "Texans", "Colts", "Jaguars", "Titans", "Broncos", "Chiefs", "Raiders", "Chargers")
final = ("6-10", "7-9", "12-4", "6-10", "10-6", "10-6", "5-11", "8-8", "12-4", "11-5", "2-14", "6-10", "13-3", "2-14", "4-12", "7-9")
results = dict(zip(teamName, final))

inp = raw_input("To find your team's final record for last season please type in their name (Ravens, Texans and etc) : ")
if inp in results:
    print("The ", inp, "final record for 2012-2013 was ", results[inp])
else:
    print("Oops, check your team name and try again!")
```